# Javascript: Accessing multi-dimensional object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, object, multidimensional-array

I'm currently working on a JS-based form processor that takes form fields and defines them as multiple-level objects based on the `name=` attribute:

```
<input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="12" name="ui.house.occupant.adult.count">
```

Using the form2js plugin, it creates an object. In this instance, `console.log` displays the ui object as follows:
http://i58.tinypic.com/2gy9duu.jpg

However, whenever I try to access this property in my JS code with anything such as `alert(ui.house.occupant.adult.count)`, it throws the error that `house` is undefined. You can see: http://i59.tinypic.com/2guz7s7.jpg

I'm racking my brain trying to figure out what the problem is. When I use `alert(ui.house)`, it returns a blank alert.
This leads me to think that the `form2js` has not actually properly processed the form data before I try to access it, however I've tried to use things such as `setTimeout` to no avail.

*For context, I am loading an external CSV file which pre-populates the form fields with data that users can choose from, hence why the second screenshot is shown inside of an $.ajax function.*

Thanks!

Edit: More complete example of code:

```
<fieldset id="user_input">
<div class="question_row">
    <label for="ui.house.ng.available">Is natural gas available in your street?</label>
    <div class="question">
        <input type="radio" name="ui.house.ng.available" value="True"> Yes
        <input type="radio" name="ui.house.ng.available" value="False"> No
        <input type="radio" name="ui.house.ng.available" value="False"> Don't know
    </div>
</div>
<div class="question_row">
    <label for="ui.house.occupant.adult.count">How many people live in your home?</label>
    <div class="spec_people question">
        Adults: 
        <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="12" name="ui.house.occupant.adult.count">
        Children: 
        <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="12" name="ui.house.occupant.child.count">
    </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

And the complete Ajax function - this pulls in an external CSV and populates the form fields with `<option>` elements as well as limiting attributes.

```
var ui = new Object;

// Load our external spreadsheet containing constants, questions, and other definitions. Format it nicely.
$.ajax({
    url: "DSD_Master_Constants.csv",
    async: false,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (csvd) {
        data = $.csv2Array(csvd);
                    // call a function on complete 
        $.each(data, function(index, rows){
            // 0  Constant Type
            // 1  Constant category 
            // 2  Constant subcategory          
            // 3
            // 4
            // 5
            // 6
            // 7  Value (min)   
            // 8  Value (max)   
            // 9  Custom option? (separate with comma)  
            // 10 Custom option value (same sequence)   
            // 11 Unit of measurement   
            // 12 Field type
            // 13 Helpful tip
            // 14 Object code
            if(rows[0] == 'User'){  // Populate User Input Fields
                var inputf = $("[name='"+rows[14]+"']");
                var htmldat = '';
                switch(rows[12]){
                    case 'number':
                        inputf.attr({
                            value: rows[7],
                            placeholder: rows[7],
                            min: rows[7],
                            max: rows[8]
                        });
                        break;
                    case '':    // must be text field
                        break;
                    case 'select':
                        if(rows[9] == ''){  // No custom option, means use min and max values
                            var minno = rows[7];
                            var maxno = rows[8];

                            while(minno <= maxno){
                                htmldat += '<option value="' + minno + '">' + minno + ' ' + rows[11] + '</option>       \
                                ';
                                minno = parseFloat(minno) + 1;
                            }
                            inputf.html(htmldat);
                        } else {    // Must be using a custom option/value set
                            var custom = rows[9].split(', ');
                            var customv = rows[10].split(', ');
                            for(var a in custom){
                                if(customv[a] == ''){ customv[a] = custom[a]; }
                                htmldat += '<option value="' + customv[a] + '">' + custom[a] + '</option>   \
                                ';
                            }
                            inputf.html(htmldat);
                            htmldat = '';
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'radio':

                        break;  
                }

            }
        });
        ui = $("#user_input").toObject();   // Splits form data into objects and sub-objects, based on delimiter (in this case, period '.')
        console.log(ui);
    },
    complete: function () {
        alert(ui.house.occupant.adult.count);
    }
});
```

I hope that makes sense - I tried to simplify it to save people having to go through my entire code - my bad!

Comment: Please give a more complete example of your code: see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve; One way is to put your code in jsfiddle. 
Also please use code blocks instead of screenshots.
Guessing it's a scope problem, but can't tell until the big picture is shown. (Especially where the ui object is declared)

Comment: what is the scope of ui variable?

Comment: The `ui` variable is a global object set that will be used in other functions within the current page - hope that answered what you meant by your question.

Comment: put another `console.log(ui);` before the `alert`

Comment: It appears exactly as before: http://i58.tinypic.com/2gy9duu.jpg. Whenever I use the 'copy path' feature in Firebug on the ui>house>occupant>adult>count child object, it gives me `ui.house.occupant.adult.count`, which leads me to believe the `ui` object is being formatted and populated correctly.

Comment: Can I confirm: console.log(ui) inside the complete function shows the correct object? Put a console.log(ui) right after the whole ajax call and see if it gets the correct object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you did ui = $("#user_input").toObject();
ui became a field in your ui object.

to access house you need to do ui.ui.house.

look carefully at what form2js returns

Comment: You are a god. Thank you very much - I've spent the last two days racking my brain - I guess to get around this all I would need to do is remove the 'ui.' at the start of each input field. However, I already have functions and selectors based off of the existing 'name's, so I've just redefined the `ui` object as `ui = ui.ui;`. Thank you, sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML you provided, there is no input element with an ID of 'user_input' as referenced in your code:

```
ui = $("#user_input").toObject();   // Splits form data into objects and sub-objects, based on delimiter (in this case, period '.')
```

Maybe you haven't included all your HTML, but from what you've provided, it appears that you're trying to access an element that doesn't exist.

Comment: The entire form is wrapped in a `<fieldset id="user_input">`, I forgot to include that in my HTML snippet. Sorry!